# Home key causing many instances of Game in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

when I am playing the game and I press the Home Key. The view is gone which is normal but when I start the game again a new game is started previous game is not resumed which is causing a lot of problem can any one help me with this issue?

Comment: Try debugging your code... checking for entry points...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b)
    {
        super.onCreate(b);
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


    }
```

Doing this solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

add   `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"`   to your activity in AndroidManifest

Answer (score 0):

You are probably creating a new instance of the game in an onResume method, so check all your lifecycle methods.

Comment: I have checked no multiple instances. What next now?

Comment: well start tracing your code backwards from the method you use to instantiate your game (ctrl+alt+h in eclipse will show all places its called from)